# Dynamically setting width of element

Tags: jquery

Anyone any ideas why this code below is not working? I am targeting a div which has some inline styles set from another piece of JS I dont control - I want to override them and set the width of the element to match the height:

```
var vidiFrameHeight = $(".fancybox-content").outerHeight();
$(".fancybox-content").css("width",vidiFrameHeight+"px !important");
```

It just does not work... Not sure why! I can target the element and add a class (so this works `$(".fancybox-content").addClass("makeMeSquare");` - but then no way in CSS (to my knowledge) to read the value of the element height and set the width to be the same?

Why would the above not work? I cant figure this out... driving me mad!

Below is the HTML markup. Width and height are dynamic as set by another js file.

```
<div class="fancybox-content makeMeSquare" style="width: 1427.56px; height: 803px;"><iframe id="fancybox-frame1668086531807" name="fancybox-frame1668086531807" class="fancybox-iframe" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ABC?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Please add HTML too. Maybe your element is in flex display and just ignores your width setting? Have you inspected element if your code adds any values? Maybe external JS just immediately overwrites your code?

Comment: I think it must be the overwrite thing - but the inline styles of the element shoud get overwritten by my jquery if the !important attribute is included?

Comment: No, because most likely your external script just overwrites your setup (simply removes it from element)

Answer (score 0):

SORTED IT... added my code to happen after a short delay to overwrite the other JS...

Comment: That sound like postponing issue, not solving it.